# how to create a help file in .net?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want to create one help file for my whole application. and once user press help button next to any input control then appropriate help topic from file should get display. how can i create this functionality in vb.net?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are good tools for creating compiled HTML help files (.chm)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023/what-are-good-tools-for-creating-compiled-html-help-files-chm)

Answer (score 1):

The .CHM file format (Compiled HTML) is the current format used for help files wit Winforms/WPF .Net application.

There are a variety of ways to create CHM files. I'd suggest checking out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023/what-are-good-tools-for-creating-compiled-html-help-files-chm) for more details on how to accomplish this.

For ASP.Net applications, you would need to generate your own help pages.